# parametric naming of nodes in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to generate a graph with nodes and edges names by their coordinates in the graph, something like:

```
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}
  \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
     \draw (1.5*\x,2.5*\y) circle (3mm) node (\x and \y);
```

that is naming node by its coordinates as (2 and 4). How can I do this? Note that later I want to use this node names to generate connections in another loop, something like

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}
\draw[->] (1.5*\x and 4) -- (1.5*(\x+1) and 4);
```

Can this, or something equivalent to this be done?

Comment: I edited a bit your post to make it a little more readable. You can improve your formatting by indenting code lines with 4 spaces or by using the button with the braces to make the code 'stick out'. `:)`

Answer (score 9):

There is a big problem with naming nodes as such since decimals would mean the angles on the shape border as in `(node.south)` or `(node.45)`. So in my opinion you should stick with the integers strictly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}{
  \foreach \y in {1,...,4}{
\begin{scope}[x=1.5cm,y=2.5cm]
     \draw (\x,\y) circle (3mm) node (n\x\y){};
\end{scope}
    }
}
\foreach \x[count=\xnext from 2] in {1,...,5}{
\draw[->] (n\x 4) -- (n\xnext 4);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are perfectly right: stick with the integers strictly! But your naming convention `n\x\y` is not perfect with number above nine. Using something like `n-\x-\y` should be more secure...

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can, you just have to be careful to name them properly and make sure that when you try to access them that you are doing so with the same name:

[image]

### Notes:

- The nodes are named `(0and 1)` ... `(6and 4)`. Note that there is no space with the `and` and the `\x` coordinate.  You can see this if you replace `node (\x and \y) {} ;` with

  ```
    node (\x and \y) {(\x and \y)};
  ```

  This is not a problem, but just something to be aware of. But, as Jake mentioned, you can have them named `(1 and 2)` if you use node `(\x\space and \y)` in which case when you attempt to access them you also need to include the `\space`.
- Since normal math calculations are usually performed as a decimal, I used `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{<csname>}{<expression>}` to ensure that we are only working with integers.
- I adjusted the range of the `foreach` that accesses the nodes to `3` to ensure that you don't try to access a node such as `(7and 4)`, which the original code was attempting to do. Also, `1.5*5` yields `7.5`, so not sure which node you want to access here.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}
  \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
     \draw (1.5*\x,2.5*\y) circle (3mm) 
        node (\x and \y) {} ;
\foreach \x in {1,...,3}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\XnameA}{1.5*\x}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\XnameB}{1.5*(\x+1)}%
    \draw[->] (\XnameA and 4) -- (\XnameB and 4);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to name the  nodes  by their coordinates in the graph is `\x;\y`. With this syntax, you can use a node like this `\draw (0;1)` . It's like coordinates and only the separator is different. If you need to draw complex graph, it's possible to add a prefix like this `a \x;\y`.

Now in your example, there is something unclear :

```
 \draw (1.5*\x,2.5*\y) circle (3mm) node (\x and \y){};
```

You use a node and a circle. Sometimes it's interesting but here why not only a node or only a coordinate.

1)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}{
  \foreach \y in {1,...,4}{
      \path (1.5*\x,2.5*\y) coordinate [draw,circle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt] (\x;\y);
    }
} 
 \foreach \j in {1,...,4}{\draw[->] (0;\j) -- (1;\j);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

2)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}{
  \foreach \y in {1,...,4}{
      \node[circle,minimum width=3mm,draw] (\x;\y)  at (1.5*\x,2.5*\y)  {} ;
    }
} 
 \foreach \j in {1,...,4}{\draw[->] (0;\j) -- (1;\j);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

3)

If you really want circles and nodes why not circles and coordinates to avoid `{}`

The code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}{
  \foreach \y in {1,...,4}{
      \draw (1.5*\x,2.5*\y) circle [radius = .3 cm]  coordinate[circle]  (\x;\y);   
    }
} 
 \foreach \j in {1,...,4}{\draw[->] (0;\j) -- (1;\j);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

4) Now to access the nodes, I think it's preferable to avoid calculations. Logically the couple of integers `(\x;\y)` denotes a single node (it's a bijection). It will be interesting to know why you need to use something like `1.5*\x` to design a node.

5) A more complex example to see all the problems

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}       
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}{
  \foreach \y in {1,...,3}{
      \path (1.5*\x,2.5*\y) coordinate [fill=red,circle,minimum size=3mm] (a \x;\y);
    }
}  

\begin{scope} [shift={(3.5cm,-5cm)}]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,4}{
      \foreach \y in {1,...,3}{
          \path (72*\x:1.5*\y) coordinate [fill=blue,circle,minimum size=3mm] (b \x;\y);
        }
    } 
\end{scope}

\foreach \i in {0,...,4}{
  \draw[->,] (a \i;3) to [bend left] (b \i;3);}

  \foreach \i [count=\ii from 1] in {0,...,4}{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iii{mod(\ii,5)}
  \draw[->,blue] (b \i;3) to [bend left]  (b \iii;3);}  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]